# NGINX mask a url redirect

Tags: nginx

I have a url `api.domain.com` that I am trying to redirect to `domain.com/api` BUT I want to preserve the look that it's still `api.domain.com`

I have tried the following

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.domain.com;

        location ~ ^/ {
                rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.com/api/$1 break;
        }
}
```

But when I hit an endpoint eg `api.domain.com/user/1` in the browser it displays as `domain.com/api/user/1`.

Is it possible to get the domain to visually stay as `api.domain.com/user/1`

Comment: Take a look at the `proxy_pass` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to serve api.domain.com from domain.com/api. You just need to define the root parameter accordingly.

Assuming the root directive for domain.com is **`/server/path/to/domain.com/html`**, in your case, it will become **`/server/path/to/domain.com/html/api`**.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com;
    root /server/path/to/domain.com/html/api;

    location / {
        # Whatever you want to do
    }
}
```